# Do these expansions make sense?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I mean

```
Series[DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> $$ \delta (0)+O\left(x^4\right)+\frac{1}{6} \delta ^{(3)}(0) x^3+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \delta ''(0)+x \delta '(0)$$

and

```
Series[FractionalPart[x]^2, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> $ \text{frac}\left(x+O\left(x^6\right)\right)^2$

Comment: Got another issue with `DiracDelta`, hm? Of course, the expansion does not make sense. You apply a tool for differentiable functions (Taylor/Laurant expansion) to an entity that is not a function at all. What do you expect Mathematica to do? Obviously, it treats `DiracDelta` purely symbolically. And symbolic functions are assumed to be analytical by Mathematica in this context.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thank you for your interest and sharing  my point of view. I added another example